# Import object contained in another object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to do something like this, but using `import` rather than `require`:

```
const MySubmodule = require('react-native').MyModule.MySubmodule;
```

I tried:

```
import { MySubmodule } from 'react-native/MyModule';
import { MySubmodule } from ('react-native').MyModule;
import { MySubmodule } from 'react-native'.MyModule;
```

None of these works.

So any idea how to import a module contained in another using `import`?

Comment: Modules don't contain other modules. What does it actually `export`?

Comment: So how is this called? The fact that you need to do `MyModule.MySubmodule` to get to `MySubmodule`?

Comment: In commonjs, it's just objects containing other objects. In ES6 modules, there is no such thing. The only thing that matters for importing is how it was exported. Can you show us that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to **import `MyModule` completely, and can then separately destructure it** to get the parts you are interested in:

```
import {MyModule} from 'react-native';

const {MySubmodule} = MyModule;
```

---

The `import` statement does not support directly destructuring exports. See also [this Babel issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4996) for some more info.

Comment: You can do it in one line `import { MyModule: { MySubmodule }} from 'react-native'` --- _edit: nope_

Comment: @evolutionxbox That's not valid syntax.

Comment: @timo no? You can't destructure like this... hmmmmmmm

Comment: @Bergi no I am enlightened